# $P(h\leq k)=P(t \leq k),\forall k\in \mathbb{R}$ implies $h=t$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider the measurable space $(A,\mathcal{A})$. Let $h,t:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be mesurable functions. Show that If $P(h\leq k)=P(t \leq k),\forall k\in \mathbb{R}, \forall P$ probability on $(A,\mathcal{A})$, then $h(x)=t(x),\forall x\in A$.

As far as I understand, it says that random variables with the same distribution functions for all possible probabilities are equal.

It holds that for all $k$ and $P$,

$$\int_{(-\infty,k]}h dP=\int_{(-\infty,k]}t dP \iff \int_{(-\infty,k]}(h-t) dP=0 \implies h-t=0 \ a.e. \text{ on } (-\infty,k].$$

I cannot go further

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suppose it wouldn't hold true. Can you build a probability measure $P$ such that $P(h\leq k) \neq P(t\leq k)$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your statement *is not* about probability measures on $\mathbb{R},$ it's about probability measures on $A$. So the statement is that you have a fixed pair of maps, $h$ and $t$ and *no matter* the probability measure on $A,$ they have the same distribution.

This is a somewhat different statement.

If the two maps are not equal, simply pick $x$ such that $h(x)>t(x)$ (without loss of generality, $h$ is the map attaining the larger value). 
 Note also that $\delta_x$ is a probability measure on the power set $\sigma$-algebra. Hence, it's a probability measure on $\mathcal{A}$. Now $\delta_x(t\leq t(x))=1$ by definition and, likewise, $\delta_x(h\leq t(x))=0$. Thus, if the two maps are not equal, there is a probability distribution observing the difference.

Comment: Let me put the pieces together. W.l.o.g. $h>t$ were assumed. By observing that $x\in\{w:t(w)\leq t(x)\}$ and $x\notin \{w:h(w)\leq t(x)\}$ you infered that $0=\int_{(-\infty,t(x))} hd\delta_x \neq \int_{(-\infty,t(x))} td\delta_x=1$. So by contraposition, I have the desired result,i.e. for all k and for all probability, $h=t$.

Comment: You're still integrating in $\mathbb{R}.$ The argument is: $x\in \{t\leq t(x)\}\cap \{x\}$ so $\delta_x(\{t\leq t(x)\})=1.$ Furthermore, $x\not\in \{h\leq t(x)\},$ so $\delta_x(\{h\leq t(x)\})=0$. Then, apply contraposition.